# django-cms "summary view" aggregating content from multiple pages

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

Django==1.5.1
django-cms==2.4.1

I'd like to make something like a summary view from all the child pages of a selected page in django-cms, pulling out title, truncated content etc with a more... link for each listed child. I've managed to get titles and paths just fine, but im struggling to get content from the placeholders.

I have a templatetag like this:

```
from cms.models import Page
from cms.utils.page_resolver import get_page_from_path

from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('news_summary_item.html')
def get_news_items():
    news_root = get_page_from_path('news')
    newsitems = news_root.children.filter(published=True)
    return {'newsitems':newsitems}
```

and here is the template its using:

```
{% load cms_tags menu_tags %}
<ul>
{% for item in newsitems %}
    <li><a href="/{{ item.get_path }}">{{ item.get_title }}</a>
        {% for placeholder in item.placeholders.all %}
            # {% show_placeholder placeholder.slot item current_language %} #
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Can anyone help with getting the placeholder content here? Ideally, id like to be able to pass it through truncatewords_html to just get a summary, but open to other ways to get the same effect.

Thanks for any tips/pointers!

Comment: Works for me, be sure to put placeholder_tags in your `{% load ... %}` and use `{% render_placeholder placeholder %}` in your template loop.

Comment: Thanks for this. I needed to do the exact same thing and had no idea where to start!

Comment: `get_page_from_path` is no more on `cms.utils.page_resolver`, it has been moved in `cms.utils.page` (I'm using djangocms 3.7)

Comment: https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/page.py#L79

Answer (score 3):

I had to index CMS content in one project and I get the content of each placeholder, and the content of a placeholder is stored in the plugins attached to it

**How te get the content of a CMSPlugin in a view?**

```
from cms.models import CMSPlugin

plugin = CMSPlugin.objects.filter(plugin_type='TextPlugin')[0]  # Get first text plugin
# This return the body/content of the plugin:
plugin_content = plugin.get_plugin_instance()[0].body
```

If you would like to manage other plugins like `PicturePlugin` you could get the "alt" text like:

```
plugin_picture_content = plugin.get_plugin_instance()[0].alt
```

**How to get the content of CMSPlugin in a template?**

```
# plugin_object containing a CMSPlugin
{{plugin_object.get_plugin_instance.0.body}}
```

I supose when you want to get the content, we are talking about `TextPlugin`, you have to be carefull here because only the plugin type `TextPlugin` has the attribute `body`, the `PicturePlugin` has the attribute `alt` and the `LinkPlugin` has the attribute `href` etc...

**Solution adapted for your problem**

You are doing a loop over ***placeholders***, so you need to get ***all the plugins*** for each placeholder and get the content of each plugin, because the content of the placeholders as I mentioned before are stored in the plugins attached to it (TextPlugin, PicturePlugin, LinkPlugin...).

```
...    ...    ...
{% for placeholder in item.placeholders.all %}  # Loop over placeholders
    {% for plugin in placeholder.get_plugin_list %}  # Get plugins for each placeholder
        {{plugin.get_plugin_instance.0.body|striptags}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
...    ...    ...
```

And to ensure that you only show the content of `TextPlugin` and not from other plugins you could do:

```
...    ...    ...
{% for placeholder in item.placeholders.all %}  # Loop over placeholders
    {% for plugin in placeholder.get_plugin_list %}  # Get plugins for each placeholder
        {% if 'TextPlugin' in plugin.plugin_type %}
            {{plugin.get_plugin_instance.0.body|striptags}}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
...    ...    ...
```